# Jquery Datatables server-side processing with PHP with MSSQL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables, server-side

I am following this [tutorial](https://coderexample.com/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/) to apply datatables server side processing in PHP, MSSQL and AJAX.

I adjusted the mentioned code to my requirements. Here is my index page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>Datatable</title>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var dataTable = $('#grid').DataTable( {
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "ajax":{
                        url :"grid-data.php",
                        type: "post", 
                        error: function(){
                            $(".grid-error").html("");
                            $("#grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
                            $("#grid_processing").css("display","none");

                        }
                    }
                } );
            } );
        </script>
        <style>
            div.container {
                margin: 0 auto;
                max-width:760px;
            }
            div.header {
                margin: 100px auto;
                line-height:30px;
                max-width:760px;
            }
            body {
                background: #f7f7f7;
                color: #333;
                font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue",HelveticaNeue,Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header"><h1>DataTable demo</h1></div>
        <div class="container">
            <table id="grid"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Country</th>
                            <th>Territory</th>
                            <th>Market</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is grid-data.php

```
<?php

$servername = "******";
$username = "******";
$password = "******";
$dbname = "mydatabase";

$dbDB = new PDO("odbc:Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;Server=******,1456;Database=mydatabase;Port=1456", $username, $password);
$requestData= $_REQUEST;

$columns = array( 
    0 =>'Country', 
    1 => 'Territory',
    2=> 'Market' );

$sql = "SELECT Country, Territory, Market ";
$sql.=" FROM mydatabase.mytable";

$nRows = $dbDB->query("SELECT count(*) from mydatabase.mytable")->fetchColumn(); 
$totalData = $nRows;
$totalFiltered = $totalData;

$sql = "SELECT Country, Territory, Market ";
$sql.=" FROM mydatabase.mytable WHERE 1=1";
if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {
    $sql.=" AND ( Country LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";    
    $sql.=" OR Territory LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR Market LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' )";
}

$nRowsSearch = $dbDB->query($sql)->fetchColumn(); 
$totalFiltered = $nRowsSearch;

$sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";

$data = array();
$query = 'SELECT Country, Territory, Market FROM mydatabase.mytable WHERE 1=1';

foreach ($dbDB->query($query) as $row) {
    $nestedData=array(); 
    $nestedData[] = $row["Country"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["Territory"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["Market"];

    $data[] = $nestedData;

} 

$json_data = array(
            "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), 
            "data"            => $data  
            );

echo json_encode($json_data); 

?>
```

The data is loaded correctly in my table but all the features like search and changing the length and ordering.. are not working.

Can you please advise me what I am missing in my grid-data.php ? Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to implement server side pagination and changing length, probably you should send which page you are on, pagelength and such stuff.

Make sure you pass page number, page length to your API and then at server side write some logic to pick only Page length number of records and based on pagenumber.

[I hope this is what you might be looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48867940/how-to-implement-pagination-with-serverside-get-api-in-datatables/48898762#48898762).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, you can use `ssp.class.php` that is available in `/examples/server_side/scripts` folder when you [download DataTables library](https://datatables.net/download/download).

There is also a sample script `server_processing.php` in `/examples/server_side/scripts` folder that shows how to use SSP class.

Comment: I also recommend looking at ssp.class.php instead.  It's well tested and probably a little simpler than that other method.  You never have to even look at the ssp.class.php code.  Get it from github.

https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php

Answer (score -1):

```
if(!empty($search)){
        $sql ="SELECT * FROM t_penalty_list WHERE";
        $sql.=" l_code LIKE '%{$search}%'";
        $sql.=" OR cus_name LIKE '%{$search}%'";
        $sql.=" OR cus_phone LIKE '%{$search}%'";
        $sql.=" OR penalty_date LIKE '%{$search}%'";
    }else{
        $sql ="SELECT * FROM t_penalty_list WHERE 1=1";
        if(!empty($is_status)){
            if($is_status == 1){
                $sql.=" AND amount_dept <= 0";
            }elseif($is_status ==2){
                $sql.=" AND amount_dept > 0";
            }
            $totalData = count($this->_penalty->selectRaw($sql));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dont just copy paste code, you should also explain what you have done!