# DataTables - I don't want to load all data at once?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a question about the JQuery PlugIn `DataTables`.

My Table has more than 5000 rows and it takes more than 30 sec to load the site and I don't want that.

I wanted to ask if it is possible to only load the first 10 rows and then with pagination click "next" and it loads the next 10 rows?

I want to do it using the DataTables.

Comment: The feature you are looking for is called *Server Side Processing". Here is an example: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48867940/how-to-implement-pagination-with-serverside-get-api-in-datatables